# using ifstream in c++

Tags: c++, file

I have the following code to read in from a file

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
   ifstream myFile(argv[1]);
   queue<String> myQueue;
   if(myFile.is_open())
      {
         while(...
         ///my read here
      }
}
```

I have input file like this

```
1234 345
A 2 234
B 2 345
C 3 345
```

I want to do the equivalent of this in the read loop

```
myQueue.push("1234");
myQueue.push("345");
myQueue.push("A");
myQueue.push("2");
myQueue.push("234");
myQueue.push("B");
...
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string input;
myFile >> input;
myQueue.push(input);
```

Untested but I believe it works.

By the way, if you want to parse the whole file:

```
while(myFile>>input)
```

Thanks to rubenvb for reminding me

Comment: but i thought myFile >> input would put the whole line into input "A 2 234" for example? I want to dilimite my input at a space or return character.

Comment: `ifstream` consumes all whitespace before reading the value. To read a whole line you would use something like `getline(myFile, input)`

Comment: You should not check for `eof()`, but instead check the extraction directly: `while( myFile >> input )` This catches all read errors. (it uses the implicit conversion to bool that every C++ stream supports.) You can do the same thing with getline: `while geline(myFile, input) )`

Comment: Yes, that's smarter. Typo on getline!

Comment: Ya, ended up switching to myFile>>input because .eof() was giving the last value in the file twice.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
   if (argc < 2)
   {
      return -1;
   }

   ifstream myFile(argv[1]);

   queue<string> myQueue;
   string input;
   while(myFile >> input)
   {
         myQueue.push(input);
   }
}
```

Comment: this is essentially what I ended up doing, great answer!

Comment: My advice: Follow the coding style of the surrounding code. Be consistent for the sake of the person who will read it after you :). Personally I use braces generously. I believe they can prevent you from writing really hard to find bugs.

Comment: Use braces at all times so when the code needs to increase in complexity, readability doesn't suffer and so the person to follow you doesn't have to add them after the fact.